# Jquery appending specific tags

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to append everything in a div, except for the input button. Is there a way I can use maybe a `not` method in Jquery? Also it's only targeting my first span block . Here's a fiddle with the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/64/

### JQuery

```
(function(){
    $('.select_listing').on('click',function () {
       $('.saved_listing').append($(this).parent().find('span').html());
    });
})();​
```

### HTML

```
<div class="boxes"> 
    <span> Matt </span>
    <span> 123 Fake Street </span>
    <input type="button" class="select_listing" value="add">
</div>

<div class="boxes"> 
    <span> James </span>
    <span> 123 Real Street </span>
    <input type="button" class="select_listing" value="add">
</div>

<div class="saved_listing"> </div>
​
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do, could you be a bit clearer.

Comment: Query the div & the input. Convert them both toString. Replace the occurence IN the div OF the input string.

Comment: basically I wanted to append into my `saved_listing` div everything *excluding* the input button.

Comment: jQuery has a `:not` operator to invert a selector, so `:not(input)` in your case.

Comment: I think you just need to remove the .html() to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Plenty of answer already, while I was having fun coming up with this one: `$(this).parent().children().clone().not('input').appendTo('.saved_listing');`. Quite concise.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could work:

```
(function(){

    $('.select_listing').on('click',function () { 
        $('.saved_listing').append($(this).parents(".boxes").find('span'));
    });

})();​
```

Let me know.

**Edit**

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9NBKN/

It appears to move the elements, do you wanted that? Or do you want the elements to be copied?

**Edit 2**

Update the fiddle to copy instead of moving the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/9NBKN/3/
(Basically I used the "clone" method).

Comment: I prefer they be copied, is there a method for that?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're going for?

```
(function(){
    $('.select_listing').on('click',function () {
        // Create a copy of .boxes and append to .saved_listing
        var htmlContent = $(this).closest('.boxes').clone().appendTo('.saved_listing');
        // Remove input
        htmlContent.find('input').remove();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/66/

```
(function() {

    $('.select_listing').on('click', function() {
        // Get the parent, and clone it!
        var pdiv = $(this).parents('.boxes').clone();

        // In the cloned parent, remove the button!
        pdiv.find("input.select_listing").remove();

        // Append to saved_listing the modified pdiv!
        pdiv.appendTo(".saved_listing");
    });

})();​
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is this line `.find('span').html()`

This statement gets the html of only the first span that are queried on . You need to loop in such cases..

Try the approach below..

```
(function() {

    $('.select_listing').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $span = $this.closest('div.boxes').find('span');
        var html = '';
        $span.each(function() {
            html += $(this).html();
        });
        $('.saved_listing').append(html);
    });

})();​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/69/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".boxes").children().not("input[type='button']")
```

The not() function will filter out the element within the selector

Answer (score 0):

Just run an `each()` through all the siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/72/

```
(function(){

    $('.select_listing').on('click',function () {

        $(this).siblings().each(function() {            
            $('.saved_listing').append($(this).html());
        });

    });

})();​
```

**EDIT:**
That way, you aren't unnecessarily traversing up to traverse back down.